# How to fix ModuleNotFoundError : No module named

Tags: python, pycharm, pytest

I am using pytest framework (python /pycharm).
when I run the tests directly by clicking on the folder -right click and select run pytest in abc - it works fine BUT when I am trying to run it via terminal, it gives me the following error
I have trying removing **init** file in the folder as suggested in other forums but still get the below error which I am copied below for your reference

```
___________________________________________________________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting Test_Results_My_Profile_Module.py _________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\SyAutomation\automation-tests\ZProjects\AutomationSy\regpytestframework\Test_Results_My_Profile_Module.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
Test_Results_My_Profile_Module.py:11: in <module>
    from ZProjects.AutomationSy.Pages.employmentPage import EmploymentpageMethods
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ZProjects'
!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection
```

Comment: Pycharm is probably using a virtualenv for the project, but when you try to run CLI you are running outside of the virtualenv.

Comment: How do i configure, so that i can run it successfully via terminal ? any idea

Comment: Also make sure to use `python -m pytest` instead of calling `pytest` directly (in case you didn't...).

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to let python know where your code is, by default it looks in your current directory and in `site-packages`. One way to do that is by creating a [python package](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/). This effectively installs your code in `site-packages`

An easier way to do that however, is to use the environment variable PYTHONHPATH (which is probably what pycharm does). This environment variable is used by python to look for extra code. So you just have to do:

Powershell

```
$Env:PYTHONPATH = "C:\SyAutomation\automation-tests\ZProjects"
```

Shell

```
export PYTHONPATH="C:\SyAutomation\automation-tests\ZProjects"
```

Windows terminal

```
setx PYTHONPATH "C:\SyAutomation\automation-tests\ZProjects"
```